# how to launch "Settings for Google Apps" via Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, google-apps

How to open the "Settings for Google Apps" using intent, with below code I can open the settings screen only, but i need to open the specific section of the Settings for google app (Google Pay)

```
fun openApp(context: Context, packageId: String) {
    try {
        val intent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageId)
        if (intent != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }else{
            context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))
        }
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        openPlayStore(context, packageId)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_PAYMENT_SETTINGS))

Answer (score 0):

google pay package name for india = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user"

```
val package = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user"

val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$package")
startActivity(intent)
```